# Are the first few characters of the two strings are quite similar together in R?

Tags: r, equality

i have a data set and i need to compare the first few character of two string in R, consider two string like :
Allison, Master Hudson Trevor
 and Allison, Miss Helen Loraine .
these two are in the same column and different rows , all of my data set is like this and it is necessary to compare each two string together until comma , if these two are the same ,return yes and else return no.
i am new in r ,
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to extract the first word with `word`

```
library(stringr)
out <- word(str1) == word(str2)
out
#[1] TRUE
```

From the logical index, it becomes easier to convert to 'Yes/No'

```
c("No", "Yes")[out +1]
```

---

Or a `base R` option involves removing the strings after the `,` and then compare

```
sub(",.*", "", str1) == sub(",.*", "", str2)
```

---

If these are two columns in a dataset, the same can be done by extracting the columns

```
out <- with(df1, word(col1) == word(col2))
```

and do the rest as above

#### data

```
str1 <- "Allison, Master Hudson Trevor"
str2 <- "Allison, Miss Helen Loraine"
```